# PyQt5 Crashes While Plotting with PyQtGraph in Real Time

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, real-time, pyqtgraph

I'm currently using a LabView DAQ program, but I need some functionality that LabView doesn't offer. So I created a program using Python that reads inputs from the NIDAQ, converts them, plots to the screen, and stores the values in a local database. To optimize the system, I use a thread to read and process the pressure card, a thread to read the thermocouple card, and a thread to pull the channels I need and combine them into a Numpy array to pass to the main GUI thread. Since the different channels plot to different axes, I loop through the array and plot them to their individual axis.

I wrote a DAQ simulator that generates semi-random values so I don't have to carry the hardware around. I think I have the bare minimum code to simulate the problem, still using two of the worker threads.

I've tried multiple ways to plot the data, and this is the best I've been able to get; about 5 minutes and the GUI becomes unresponsive, and occasionally a full crash. I've profiled the program without any useful results. Or, I just don't know how to interpret the results.

[Python Memory Profiler Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUqOd.png)

```
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QFrame,  QTabWidget, QApplication

pg.mkQApp()
pg.setConfigOption('useOpenGL', True)

webster = {0: {'name': 'Tubing'}, 
           1: {'name': 'Annulus'}}
output_array = np.full((20, 16), -1.0)

output_array[0, 0] = 0
output_array[0, 1] = 0
output_array[0, 6] = 0
output_array[0, 7] = 0
output_array[0, 8] = 0
output_array[0, 13] = 0

output_array[1, 0] = 1
output_array[1, 1] = 0
output_array[1, 6] = 0
output_array[1, 7] = 0
output_array[1, 8] = 1
output_array[1, 13] = 0

p_buffer = np.zeros((1, 1), dtype=np.float64)
p_cal = np.array([[-1.000001, -1.000001, -1.000001, -1.000001, -1.000001], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]], dtype=float)

p_fluctuation = 0.004

run_thread = False
recording = True
daq_time = time.time()

d_symbol = '\u00b0'
settings = ('', 0, 2, 0, 20000, 0, 0, 2, 0, 400, 0, 0, 2, 0, 100000, -100000)
color_list = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255), (255, 0, 255), (255, 100, 0), (255, 0, 150), (138, 29, 29), (17, 12, 168)]

# Pressure Inputs DAQ Thread
class PressureThread(QtCore.QThread):
    p_array = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        global run_thread, p_buffer, p_cal, p_fluctuation, recording

        while run_thread:
            if recording:
                p_buffer = np.random.uniform(low=0.995, high=1.01, size=(5, 10))
                # Average buffer
                p_mean_array = np.mean(p_buffer, axis=1)
                # Add x to negative x1
                add_array = np.add(p_mean_array, p_cal[0:1])
                # Multiply by y2 divided by x2 minus x1
                mult_array = np.multiply(add_array, 4)
                inter_array = np.add(p_cal[0:1], p_cal[1:2])
                comp_array = np.divide(mult_array, inter_array)
                # Create and combine arrays of metric and imperial 0-10k and 0-5k transducers
                twenty_k_psi_array = comp_array * 20000
                twenty_k_mpa_array = comp_array * 20000 * 6.89476
                five_k_psi_array = comp_array * 5000
                five_k_mpa_array = comp_array * 5000 * 6.89476
                p_full_array = np.stack((twenty_k_psi_array, twenty_k_mpa_array, five_k_psi_array, five_k_mpa_array))
                self.p_array.emit(p_full_array)
                time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                pass

    def stop(self):
        self.exit()


# Input Calculation Thread
class SlideRuleThread(QtCore.QThread):

    tree_out = pyqtSignal(str)
    arrays = pyqtSlot(np.ndarray, name='arrays')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        global run_thread, recording, daq_time, webster, output_array
        run_thread = True

        try:
            self.thread1 = PressureThread()
            self.thread1.start()
            self.thread1.p_array.connect(self.worker)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def run(self):

        print('Running')

    def worker(self, arrays):
        global recording, daq_time, webster, output_array

        shape = arrays.shape
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = round(float(current_time - daq_time), 4)
    
        for row in output_array:
            ref_row = row[0]
            if ref_row != -1:
                # Values shift left
                row[2] = row[4]
                row[3] = row[5]
                row[4] = elapsed_time  # New value to x2

            if shape == (4, 1, 5):
                if row[1] == 0:  # Pressure array
                    if row[6] == 0:  # Pressure
                        value = arrays[int(row[7]), 0, int(row[8])]  # New y value
                        row[5] = round(value, 2)  # New value to y2
                        
                    elif row[6] == 2:  # Pressure load
                        value = (arrays[int(row[7]), 0, int(row[8])] * row[9]) + (arrays[int(row[10]), 0, int(row[11])] * row[12])  # New calculation
                        row[5] = round(value, 2)  # New value to y2
                        
        sign = ''
        self.tree_out.emit(sign)

    def stop(self):
        self.thread1.exit()
        self.exit()


# Plot Element Builder
class MultiLine(pg.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, p):
        global color_list
        """x and y are 2D arrays of shape (Nplots, Nsamples)"""
    
        x_array = np.array(x)
        y_array = np.array(y)
    
        self.path = pg.arrayToQPath(x_array.flatten(), y_array.flatten())  # self.path = pg.arrayToQPath(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), connect.flatten())
        pg.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem.__init__(self, self.path)
        self.setPen(pg.mkPen(color_list[p], width=1))
    def shape(self): # override because QGraphicsPathItem.shape is too expensive.
        return pg.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.shape(self)
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.path.boundingRect()


# Main GUI Window
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    # Initial Inputs and Variables
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.initUI()
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

        global run_thread, recording, daq_online

        self.graph = False

        self.right_left_axis = pg.AxisItem('right')
        self.right_right_axis = pg.AxisItem('right')
        self.right_left_vb = pg.ViewBox()
        self.right_right_vb = pg.ViewBox()
        self.main_plot_view = pg.GraphicsView()
        self.main_plot_view_layout = pg.GraphicsLayout()

        # GUI Items
    def initUI(self):

        # TOP LEFT FRAME
        fra_data = QFrame(self)
        fra_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 350, 210))
        fra_data.setFrameShape(QFrame.Panel)
        fra_data.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        fra_data.lineWidth()
        fra_data.midLineWidth()
        fra_data.setLineWidth(5)

        self.list_cha = QTreeWidget(fra_data)
        self.list_cha.setColumnCount(3)
        self.list_cha.setHeaderLabels(['Channel', 'Data', ''])
        self.list_cha.setGeometry(10, 10, 330, 190)
        self.list_cha.setColumnWidth(0, 180)
        self.list_cha.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.list_cha.setColumnWidth(2, 40)
        self.list_cha.addTopLevelItem(QTreeWidgetItem(0))
        self.list_cha.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, 'Pressure1')
        self.list_cha.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, 'Stopped')
        self.list_cha.topLevelItem(0).setText(2, 'psi')
        self.list_cha.addTopLevelItem(QTreeWidgetItem(1))
        self.list_cha.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, 'Pressure2')
        self.list_cha.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, 'Stopped')
        self.list_cha.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, 'psi')

        # Tabs
        fra_tabs = QFrame(self)
        fra_tabs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 1500, 950))
        fra_tabs.lineWidth()
        fra_tabs.midLineWidth()
        fra_tabs.setLineWidth(5)

        tabs = QTabWidget(fra_tabs)

        daq_tab = QWidget()

        tabs.resize(1500, 950)
        tabs.addTab(daq_tab, 'DAQ')

        # DAQ Tab
        self.fra_plot = QFrame(daq_tab)
        self.fra_plot.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.fra_plot.setGeometry(10, 40, 1480, 860)

        self.mpW = pg.PlotWidget(self.fra_plot, axisItems={'bottom': pg.DateAxisItem(utcOffset=0)})
    
        self.mpW.move(5, 5)
        self.mpW.setBackground('w')
        self.mpW.resize(1460, 850)

        self.main_axis = self.mpW.plotItem

        self.graph = True

        # Plot Settings
        self.main_axis.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=1)
        self.main_axis.setLabel('bottom', '(hh:mm:ss)')
        self.main_axis.setTitle('Just DAQ Profiler', color='b', size='20pt')

        # Axis Labels and Units
        self.main_axis.getAxis('left').setLabel('Pressure (psi)', color='#0000ff')

        # Axis Ranges
        self.main_axis.vb.setYRange(0, 100, padding=0)

        # Adjustable Horizontal Reference Lines
        self.main_axis.vb.addItem(pg.InfiniteLine(pos=100 - ((100 - 0) * 0.1), angle=0, pen=(0, 255, 0),
                                                movable=True))
        self.main_axis.vb.addItem(pg.InfiniteLine(pos=0 + ((100 - 0) * 0.1), angle=0, pen=(0, 255, 0),
                                                movable=True))

        self.mpW.show()

        self.thread3 = SlideRuleThread()
        self.thread3.start()
        self.thread3.tree_out.connect(self.treeUpdater)

    # Updates Values in Channel List Tree
    def treeUpdater(self, sign):
        
        global output_array

        for row in output_array:
            tree_row = int(row[0])
            if tree_row != -1:
                value = str(row[5])
                self.list_cha.topLevelItem(tree_row).setText(1, value)
            
                time_one = float(row[4])
                time_two = float(row[2])
                list_time = [time_two, time_one]
                value_one = float(row[5])
                value_two = float(row[3])
                list_values = [value_two, value_one]
            
                lines = MultiLine(list_time, list_values, tree_row)
                self.main_axis.addItem(lines)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The last time I commented out "self.main_axis.addItem(lines)", the code ran for 5 hours and was still perfectly responsive. But, if I uncomment it, it runs for about 4 to 5 minutes before it slowly dies and then crashes. Which is weird, because the PyQtGraph examples I've tried plotted 100,000 data points in 0.01 seconds, and in 5 minutes with 2 channels updating at 10 Hz, this is only 6,000 data points.

I'm new to Python, this is my first program, so I'm sure there's lots of things I'm doing incorrectly, or could be improved. But, through all my searching and program tweaking over the last couple months, I can't find any other examples that are similar or explain what is going on. I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

System: Windows 10 Pro 64bit, 16 GB RAM, Intel Core i7 @ 2.30GHz
Visual Studio Code: 1.71.0
Python: 3.10.6
PyQtGraph: 0.12.4
Numpy: 1.23.2

Comment: Your code is quite convoluted, but it seems to me that you're trying to access `output_array` in the UI while the thread is writing it, which clearly doesn't work well since numpy arrays are not thread safe (they are representation of direct memory addresses). If you want to keep a single array, you can only do that in a thread-safe manner (possibly using locks), but since that array doesn't seem so big, I wouldn't care about memory: just emit the signal with a copy of the array.

Comment: @musicamante I see. Why does that only affect the program while it's plotting?

Comment: Assuming my intuition is correct, because you're accessing the same object *at the same time* as it's being written. While Python doesn't normally allow concurrency, I believe that using a numpy array makes things less "safe". Try emitting a copy of the array and using that instead of using the same. By the way, globals should be avoided in any case.

Comment: @musicamante Ok, that makes sense. After looking through my code, almost all of the global variables didn't need to be global, I was just being lazy. :P So, I re-organized things and moved the global variables to where they were actually being used, and split the global array into each function. Now instead of sending a signal to the main GUI to access the updated array, I send a list to the main GUI. The code is much nicer now, so I appreciate the recommendation, but it still crashes at the same point.

Comment: Did you try to run the program in a terminal/prompt and see if you get any traceback of it?

Comment: I tried running it from the Visual Studio Code terminal, and from the Windows command prompt. Both ran until the UI became unresponsive, then the program stopped and said "Not Responding". I let it sit there for a few minutes then closed the window, and the command prompt came back up. No errors.

Comment: It's possible that the signal is emitted too often and the UI can't keep up, and in the meantime the queue is filled with other signals. Try decreasing the rate (by increasing the `time.sleep()` value). If that's the case.

Comment: I increased time.sleep() from 0.1 to 0.2 and it definitely helped. But now it became unresponsive after 15 minutes, and "Not Responding" after 17 minutes. How does PyQtGraph work then? Why does plotting a huge array, all at once, take 0.01 seconds, but this is getting backlogged adding four points each time? Does it draw one continuous line through all the points with one huge array, and I'm asking it to draw 600 lines per minute and then redraw them 10 times a second? I'm just trying to figure out, if the problem is redrawing all the lines over and over, how can I stop it from having to?

Comment: As said, your code is too convoluted and we really can't consider to "debug" it (nor we know how you changed it in the meantime). But, if you're keeping adding items *not* considering the existing ones, then the problem is probably there: QGraphicsView (which is the basis of pyqtgraph) can support thousands of items, but there's always some limit to its contents, depending on your system, and you're probably reaching it.

Comment: Ok. I was asking how PyQtGraph functions. I'm not asking you to write a program for me. By "we", are you speaking for the entire stackoverflow community?

Comment: The problem seems to be from having too many items for PyQtGraph to replot everytime. I found this out by appending the values to a dataframe, clearing the plot, then replotting the entire plot from the dataframe. This way there's only two items (each individual line) to plot. It's working great now.

Comment: No, I can't speak for everyone, but I can speak for my contribution and experience with SO rules. Obviously, there's probably somebody on Earth that could be eager to go through your ~300 lines and tell you what's wrong with it (*for free*), and maybe they're even here on SO. That's not the point: the matter of your post is conceptually vague ("it crashes") and there is no specific hint of the cause, which means that any of the "somebody" above would need to actually go through all that code without *any* clue. That's not the intent of SO: as said, it is not a debugging service.